# How to insert script into HTML element that reacts to changes of its content?

Tags: javascript, inject

Given HTML code such as the following:

```
<div id="group">
  <span id="watch">I say watch me</span>
  <span id="change">I say change me</span>
</div>
```

Is it at all possible to programatically insert code into one element that would independently act whenever it's text is changed? For example, with the above, I would like to inject code into `#watch` that would get triggered if the text of `#watch` was ever changed.

For example, if another object changed the text of `#watch` to "I saw watch me NOW", then I want the code triggered (and to subsequently change the text of `#change`).

Javascript has the `onchange` event, which says it tracks changes and executes the code associated with it, but I'm only seeing that in reference to `<select>` objects. Is there anything else like this I can use?

Comment: Are you trying to have a listener bound to the onchange of the element's innerHTML?

Comment: Not plugging frameworks, but some use dirty checking to see when values change. I can only see this as a viable option here. If value changed from what was there then do X....

Comment: @Chizzle yes, that's what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

**Classic approach: DOMSubtreeModified**

You can observe DOM mutations by listening for the [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) event. The other answer includes an example so I won't repeat one here. Note that this is labelled as a classic approach as [MDN Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) notes it is deprecated.

**Modern approach: MutationObserver**

You can observe DOM mutations by using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). I've taken your example HTML and created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsbusxvk/1/) that reports changes to the DOM element watched when the mutate! button is pressed.

HTML:

```
<div id="group">
  <span id="watch">I say watch me</span>
  <span id="change">I say change me</span>
</div>

<button id="mutate">mutate!</button>

<div id="output" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function onMutation(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    output.innerText += '\n' + mutation.type + ' ' + mutation.target.data;
  });
}


var watcher = new MutationObserver(onMutation);

// configuration of the observer:
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true
};
watcher.observe(document.getElementById('change'), config);

document.getElementById('mutate').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('change').innerText += ' ' + Date.now();
});
```

It is hard to make a really short concise example of this that is actually useful -- some output to see the events and some way of triggering an event is needed so the above example (and linked JSFiddle) have those.

**Which to use?**

I'd recommend a hybrid solution that provides a compatible fallback MutationObserver for browser platforms that do not have one (older browsers). An example of that would be [webcomponentsjs](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs).

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nsbusxvk/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to text change by

```
$('#watch').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  //do what you want here
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/3vxw7nw8/